# Is there any way to listen the youtube channel events?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

The requirement is to get events  (subscribe button click ,like button click , comments , etc ) from youtube to my Nodejs or php application.

I found some websites like livestreamalerts.com, they are providing feature like this

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You can try using [YouTube Analytics API and YouTube Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/), both APIs enable developers to retrieve YouTube Analytics data. You can start check that documentation but remember that YouTube channel owners and YouTube content owners, each of whom can access a specific set of reports.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Rebot, This are the api end points, we need to call the api and get response. I am looking for something like publish and subscribe so it will be almost real time.